# How to create an error log file after an error in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm writing a Python script and already use the `logging` library to log errors in my script, but I would like to create this error log file only after the error has appeared, can that be done?

Here's the code I have:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

fh = logging.FileHandler("log.txt")
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)

try:
    # my code
except:
    logger.exception("my message")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')


def setup_logger(name, log_file, setLevel):
    """To setup as many loggers as you want"""

    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level=setLevel)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger


error_log = setup_logger('error_logger', 'error.log', logging.ERROR)

err_log.error("ERROR YOU WANT TO PUT")
```

You can have the debug logger as `logging.DEBUG` and create as many logger with the function

Comment: It doesn't show what happened it just shows: hour - ERROR - message

Comment: as i said now you can use `err_log.error("my message")` and you can use it to put any error/ msg in the file, it writes the error with the timestamp

Comment: If I understand it right, this is for debugging my code right?